# Getting values off Active Tab Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, content-script

I know you can inject scripts into the active tab, such as below

```
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript( tabs[0].id,
        {code: 'document.getElementById("input").value ="' + youtube_url  + '";'});
    chrome.tabs.executeScript( tabs[0].id,
      {code: "document.getElementById('submit').click();"});
});
```

But how would you get values of elements in the active tab and store it .Specifically I am trying to check an "a" tag until it switches from its default href value, but I can't seem to get the value.

I am trying to get the value of: document.getElementsByTagName("a")[5].attributes.href.value;

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To detect changes in DOM see examples of using MutationObserver or simply check periodically with setTimeout/setInterval.

Comment: Yea that works, but how would I get the target node if I am working on a chrome extension, so far all I could figure out is how to inject scripts, not store elements of the page. @wOxxOm

Comment: The code you're injecting is javascript so you can use variables to store anything. You may want to use `file` parameter and a separate js file for convenience. Note that the executeScript runs the code in a different process so the outer code (that runs executeScript) cannot use the variables from inside - you can use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) instead.